# Which food writers do you take to bed?

Tags: learning, cookbook

Which food books (and I'm thinking books on food and cooking rather than recipe books) do you find on your bedside cabinet rather than on the kitchen shelves?

[McGee on Food and Cooking: An Encyclopedia of Kitchen Science, History and Culture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0684800012) keeps creeping back as it answers all those questions about why something works, or doesn't;

Anything by M. F. K. Fisher as I never tire of her simple, witty prose and sheer love of food.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/396/what-cook-books-do-you-always-come-back-to

Comment: Any question that asks users to create a list of answers (i.e. polls or list-of-X) should be make community wiki. I converted this question.

Comment: I consider this a dupe.  The difference is *way* too subtle and subjective to make this stand out.

Comment: My spouse has a cooking blog and thus is a food writer

Comment: @Din well, that is probably the most on-topic answer to this question possible.

Comment: @Dinah - I was waiting for somebody to say that...

Comment: Also, like an earlier link to McGee - this link is dead. Is someone trying to sneak in their Amazon book store or something?

Comment: Re: the duplicate issue, these books are not cookbooks.  They are better classified 'food writing', and they concern history, nutrition, science, and more nuanced discussions of technique than an average cookbook.  They tend to be light on or absent recipes and filled with personal stories, anecdotes, opinions, and general discursiveness not common to a normal cookbook.

Answer (score 4):

Jeffrey Steingarten - The Man Who Ate Everything and It Must Be Something I Ate

The New Yorker Anthology of Food Writing

Herve This - Molecular Gastronomy

Answer (score 4):

Kitchen Confidential by Anthony Bourdain.

Comment: Only if you're not planning on eating at a restaurant for breakfast.

Comment: Only if you think being a chef is incompatible with sobriety, family life, staying in one place for any meaningful amount of time, or not being angry... or if you want to be inspired to feel that way.

Answer (score 4):

*Animal, Vegetable, Miracle* by Barbara Kingsolver

*In Defense of Food* and *Omnivore's Dilemma* by Michael Pollan

Those are the ones I've been working on recently.

Comment: Add *The Botany of Desire* by Pollan.  It's less political, but as insightful about our relationship with agriculture as anything I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Ruhlman, Bourdain, and Steingarten, as others have mentioned. Alan Richman's *Fork It Over* is also really good, especially the chapters on BBQ, and the decline of the Jewish delicatessen.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Michael Ruhlman. I loved *The Making of a Chef*, and I'm working on *The Soul of a Chef*. Ruhlman can be a bit of a snob when it comes to cooking, but he loves the craft and that passion really comes through in his writing.

Also, I can highly recommend *Cod* and *Salt* by Mark Kurlansky. More history than food writing, but both are absolutely fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

I truly love the Old Foodie Blog: http://www.theoldfoodie.com/ I read it on my kindle at bedtime. And Bourdain. And Ruhlman.

Answer (score 0):

While it's pretty dense (and can help put you to sleep), Marion Nestle's *Food Politics* does a fantastic job in looking at the relation between the US Government's regulating nutrition and food supply and the big commercial food industry.

While not a "foodie" book talking about dishes and ingredients, it helps expose the root of where most of the education and communication about nutrition comes from in the United States. This shapes food culture and cooking for more of us than we sometimes realize.

Nutrition has become a culture itself and like all cultures has a heavy influence on cooking style and inspiration.

Comment: Have you read Diet for a Small Planet.  It's probably the book that started the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Heat, by Bill Buford is a fantastic read.

Answer (score 0):

These might count as either recipie books or travel books, but the two *In serach of perfection* books by Heston Blumenthal are both fascinating readings. Not sure I'll ever make the Chilli that needs a whole bottle of Jack Daniels but the effort that you can put into creating great food is truly fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

- **Nigel Slater - Toast**

  *`Strange, moving and somehow makes the reader feel nostalgia for the food crimes of the 1970s`*.
- **Jeffrey Steingarten - The Man Who Ate Everything**

  *`All of it but especially the first chapter on his attempts to perfect the art of baking bread.`*
- **Julie Powell - Julie & Julia**

  *`Makes you feel a little bit braver about tackling something ambitious.`*