# What are good resources to learn food chemistry?

Tags: food-science, additives

Does anyone know of some good resources to start learning about food chemistry?
I am thinking specifically about a description of the chemical processes involved e.g. in cooking/preparing the different foods and their relation with changes in flavor etc.

Also: do you know a reliable source to understand what is the purpose of all food additives used by the industry? Here I am not thinking about colorant/preservatives and the like, but more about the "strange supernumerary" ingredients we can see on industrial food's labels.

Comment: See also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/which-food-writers-do-you-take-to-bed, and the food-science tags on this site, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-science.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[McGee on Food and Cooking: An Encyclopedia of Kitchen Science, History and Culture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0340831499) will answer most questions on what the chemistry is behind most cooking processes, without being too academic.

Comment: For a more academic look at the chemistry of the subject find [Hervé This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herv%C3%A9_This) is one of the founders of the Molecular Gastronomy movement.

Comment: +1 excellent book, in frequent use in my home. I daren't take it to work as I'm sure someone would borrow it!

Comment: is there a particular book you would recommend to get started with molecular gastronomy?

Comment: @FordBuchanan: That book doesn't appear to be available in the U.S. for some reason, although [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Food-Cooking-Science-Lore-Kitchen/dp/0684800012/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1319143787&sr=1-1) is.  Do you know how they're related?

Comment: Yes, that's the US edition.

Answer (score 1):

To update this 2010 question, [McGee](https://www.curiouscook.com/) is still active and an excellent primary source. He has done more work in addition to the book in the accepted answer.  You might also look into [Arielle Johnson](https://www.ariellejohnson.com/about), formerly of MIT and currently Alton Brown's chief science officer.  She has a ton of experience.

I believe both McGee and Johnson have new books coming out soon.